# Write function for logout in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to write backend functionality for logout button using django

I tried using logout() function in django but once I click the logout button, it doesn't log out

Comment: If you want help debugging code, you need to post the code you have written, " tried using logout() function".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that there is an authenticated user first.

The Django docs might help:

[How to logout()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out)

[login/logout signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals)